# In Python's Matplotlib, How can I get thin images to border a main image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D matrix `Main`, a `Left` matrix whose height matches that of `Main`, and a `Top` matrix whose width matches that of `Main`. I would like all 3 to have color bars (bounded by their individual limits), and for them to be stitched together into 1 image, `Top` to top, `Left` to left of `Main`.

In the end, I would like to be able to plot this whole block within a subplot of other plots.

So far, I have been trying `axes_grid1`, and I can't get the thin matrixes (and color bars) to stick to their appropriate sides. Should I be using something else entirely though?

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# Data
n = 20
Main = np.random.randn(n, n)
Left = np.random.randn(n, 1)
Top  = np.random.randn(n, 2)

# Setup
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
ax_top   = divider.append_axes("top",   1., pad=0.)
ax_left  = divider.append_axes("left",  1., pad=0.)
ax_right = divider.append_axes("right", 1., pad=0.)

# Main
im_main = ax.imshow(Main)
clrbar_right = plt.colorbar(im_main, cax=ax_right)

# Top
im_top  = ax_top.imshow(Top.T)
ax_top_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax_top)
ax_top_top = ax_top_divider.append_axes('top', 1., pad=0.)
ax_top_clrbar = plt.colorbar(im_top, cax=ax_top_top, orientation='horizontal')

# Left
im_left = ax_left.imshow(Left)
ax_left_divider = make_axes_locatable(ax_left)
ax_left_left = ax_left_divider.append_axes('left', 1., pad=0.)
ax_left_clrbar = plt.colorbar(im_left, cax=ax_left_left)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it like that. Maybe [take a look at this](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Axes_Grid]

I think you almost had it correct but there was no need to create multiple dividers for appending the color bar axes. We can use the original divider itself. I had to play with `size` parameter of `append_axes` to get the spacing right with the code below. About adding this whole block to a subplot of another plot, that may introduce more challenges that I did not check yet.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

# Data
n = 20

Main = np.random.randn(n, n)
Left = np.random.randn(n, 1)
Top  = np.random.randn(n, 2)

# Setup
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)

# The top and left axes for images
ax_top = divider.append_axes('top',size='10%',pad=0.0)
ax_left = divider.append_axes('left',size='5%', pad=0.)

# The color bar axes
ax_top_top  = divider.append_axes('top', size='5%',pad=0.1)
ax_left_left = divider.append_axes('left',size='5%', pad=0.1)
ax_right = divider.append_axes('right',size='5%', pad=0.1)


# Main
im_main = ax.imshow(Main)
clrbar_right = plt.colorbar(im_main, cax=ax_right)

# Top
im_top  = ax_top.imshow(Top.T)
ax_top_clrbar = plt.colorbar(im_top, cax=ax_top_top, orientation='horizontal')

# Left
im_left = ax_left.imshow(Left)
ax_left_clrbar = plt.colorbar(im_left, cax=ax_left_left)

# Turn off the axis labels for the images if you like
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax_top.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax_top.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
ax_left.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax_left.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

# Switch the ticks for the color bars on the left and the top
ax_left_left.yaxis.tick_left()
ax_top_top.xaxis.tick_top()

plt.show()
```

Comment: exactly it, and more elegant than all my attempts. Thanks :)

Comment: and for future ref., you can determine the % in `size` by `'%d%%'%(int(top_depth  / n * 100))`

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the `size` tip.